# Using a managed array from C# in a sound player DLL written in Win32

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, audio, dll

I have this school assignment where we are required to make a DLL based on some a Win32 sound player/recorder and then tie it into a C# application we already made that edits sound files. I have it so if you record with the DLL it puts the recorded sound file into the main program using Marshal.Copy to copy the unmanaged byte[] from the DLL to a managed byte[] in the main program which then converts the values into shorts, which works perfectly fine. However, I would also like to do the reverse. That is to say, I would like to be able to pass a byte[] into the DLL to be played, since it currently only plays the sounds that it recorded. I looked through the documentation on the Marshal class and didn't find anything useful so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. This program is quite massive so far so I'll try to only post the relevant code. The set up I have in the DLL uses an invisible CallBack window that handles the WIM and WOM messages sent by the functions that are called outside the DLL.

The Main Program:

```
    [DllImport("RecordDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr getBytes();

    [DllImport("RecordDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int getNumBytes();

    //I thought I could use something like this to set it
    [DllImport("RecordDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern void setBytes(IntPtr wav);

    short[] storedRecording;

    //Constructor plus a ton of other irrelevant stuff here

    private void RecordStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        RecordStart.Enabled = false;
        PlayStart.Enabled = false;
        Stop.Enabled = true;
        Stop.Focus();
        RecordStatus.Text = "";
        recordStart(); //DLL function
    }

    private void StopRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        recordEnd(); //DLL function
        int numBytes = getNumBytes();
        byte[] byteArr = new Byte[numBytes];
        storedRecording = new short[numBytes];
        Marshal.Copy(getBytes(), byteArr, 0, numBytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++)
        {
            storedRecording[i] = byteArr[i];
        }
        RecordStatus.Text = "Recording loaded.";
    }

    private void PlayStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        PlayStart.Enabled = false;
        PlayPause.Enabled = true;
        Stop.Enabled = true;
        Stop.Focus();
        RecordStatus.Text = "";
        if(storedRecording != null){
            //convert the array to an unmanaged byte[] somehow?
            //then call setBytes with that byte[]?
        }
        playBegin(); //DLL function
    }
```

The Relevant Fucntions From The Record/Play DLL:

```
    static PBYTE* pSaveBuffer;

    __declspec(dllexport) BOOL CALLBACK playBegin() {
        // Open waveform audio for output

        waveform.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
        waveform.nChannels = 1;
        waveform.nSamplesPerSec = 11025;
        waveform.nAvgBytesPerSec = 11025;
        waveform.nBlockAlign = 1;
        waveform.wBitsPerSample = 8;
        waveform.cbSize = 0;

        if (waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &waveform,
            (DWORD)myHwnd, 0, CALLBACK_WINDOW))
        {
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            MessageBox(myHwnd, szOpenError, szAppName,
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) PBYTE* CALLBACK getBytes() {
        return pSaveBuffer;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) int CALLBACK getNumBytes() {
        return dwDataLength;
    }
```

From The WinProc That Is Used To Handle The waveOutOpen Message Sent To The CallbackWindow In The DLL:

```
case MM_WOM_OPEN:
        // Set up header

        pWaveHdr1->lpData = (LPSTR)*pSaveBuffer;
        pWaveHdr1->dwBufferLength = dwDataLength;
        pWaveHdr1->dwBytesRecorded = 0;
        pWaveHdr1->dwUser = 0;
        pWaveHdr1->dwFlags = WHDR_BEGINLOOP | WHDR_ENDLOOP;
        pWaveHdr1->dwLoops = dwRepetitions;
        pWaveHdr1->lpNext = NULL;
        pWaveHdr1->reserved = 0;

        // Prepare and write

        waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, pWaveHdr1, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, pWaveHdr1, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

        bEnding = FALSE;
        bPlaying = TRUE;
        return 0;
```

Hopefully that communicates sort of how it works. Despite the huge amount of code, I'm pretty sure the problem is a small one. I just need to be able to set *pSaveBuffer to contain the data from the main program. I have a feeling this could be done by converting the managed array to an unmanaged array, but like I said I have no idea if that's even possible or not. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just pass a `byte[]` on the C# side. That will be `unsigned char*` on the C++ side. Obviously pass the length too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Wait why does it become an unsigned char*?

Comment: Binary data typically represented that way. But wave API uses LPSTR which is kind of odd. So maybe you should follow suit.

Comment: Okay, so then any idea what type I would use as the equivalent of LPSTR in the prototype in my C#? And do you know how I would go about putting that LPSTR into my PBYTE?

Comment: I told you already in my first comment. Read it again. However, you are trying to run before you can walk. A common beginner's mistake. You will get utterly lost in all of this. Try to get the basics sorted and built it up slowly.